# Resize in custom HashMap - test timed out

Tags: java, hashmap, resize

I am implementing hashmap from scratch.
I have my constructor:

```
    public MyHashMap(int initialCapacity) {
        resizeFactor = 2;
        loadFactor = 0.75;
        bucketSize = initialCapacity;
        size = 0;
        buckets = createBucket();
        hashTable = createTable(bucketSize);
        for (int i = 0; i < bucketSize; i++) {
            hashTable[i] = buckets;
        }
    }
```

My put method:

```
    public void put(K key, V value) {
        if (key == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("first argument to put() is null");

        // Get hash code
        Integer hashCode = key.hashCode();
        // Compute index by modulo
        Integer index = Math.floorMod(hashCode, bucketSize);
        // Check if the item exists in the bucket
        for (Node node : hashTable[index]) {
            if (node.key.equals(key)) {
                node.value = value;
                return;
            }
        }
        hashTable[index].add(createNode(key, value));
        size += 1;

        if ( 1.0 * size/ bucketSize > loadFactor) {
            int newTableSize = bucketSize * resizeFactor;
            resize(newTableSize);
        }
    }
```

**There is some problem with my resize method because the test for resize failed and I do not seem to understand why**

```
    private void resize(int newTableSize) {
        MyHashMap hashMap = new MyHashMap(newTableSize);
            // Loop through each bucket(/index) in the current hash table
            for (int i = 0; i < bucketSize; i++) {
                // Loop through each item in current hash table's buckets
                for (Node node : hashTable[i]) {
                    hashMap.put(node.key, node.value);
                }
            }
        this.size = hashMap.size;
        this.bucketSize = newTableSize;
        this.hashTable = hashMap.hashTable;
    }
```

The test: (you may assume there is for sure nothing wrong with the test)

```
    public void testResize() {
        sanityResizeTest(new MyHashMap<>(), 16, 0.75);
        sanityResizeTest(new MyHashMap<>(32), 32, 0.75);
        sanityResizeTest(new MyHashMap<>(64, 0.5), 64, 0.5);
    }

    public static void sanityResizeTest(MyHashMap<String, Integer> m, int initialCapacity, double loadFactor) {
        // Times out after 10 seconds
        assertTimeoutPreemptively(Duration.ofSeconds(10), () -> {
            int backingArrayCapacity = sizeOfBackingArray(m);
            assertThat(backingArrayCapacity).isEqualTo(initialCapacity);
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
                m.put("hi" + i, i);
                if (1.0 * i / backingArrayCapacity > loadFactor) {
                    assertThat(sizeOfBackingArray(m)).isGreaterThan(backingArrayCapacity);
                    backingArrayCapacity = sizeOfBackingArray(m);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

```
sizeOfBackingArray:
    /** Returns the length of the backing array of the given map.
     *  Be sure that you only use one instance variable to hold the buckets,
     *  otherwise this will not work properly.
```

### What I don't understand

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: execution timed out after 10000 ms
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertTimeout.assertTimeoutPreemptively(AssertTimeout.java:158)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertTimeout.assertTimeoutPreemptively(AssertTimeout.java:119)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertTimeout.assertTimeoutPreemptively(AssertTimeout.java:101)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertTimeout.assertTimeoutPreemptively(AssertTimeout.java:97)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTimeoutPreemptively(Assertions.java:3398)
    at hashmap.TestMyHashMap.sanityResizeTest(TestMyHashMap.java:182)
    at hashmap.TestMyHashMap.testResize(TestMyHashMap.java:175)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
```

I'm not exactly sure why would it time out because the `put` and `resize` methods look fine to me.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you reusing the same `buckets` reference in your constructor? `MyHashMap hashMap = new MyHashMap(newTableSize);` is a notoriously bad idea. You should not use raw types like this and instead make your HashMap class generic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your constructor creates only one `buckets` and uses this for all `hashTable` entries:

```
    buckets = createBucket();
    hashTable = createTable(bucketSize);
    for (int i = 0; i < bucketSize; i++) {
        hashTable[i] = buckets;
    }
```

That means that no matter what hashcode your keys have, they end up in the same `buckets` list.

Your `resize()` method then does excessive work:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < bucketSize; i++) {
            // Loop through each item in current hash table's buckets
            for (Node node : hashTable[i]) {
                hashMap.put(node.key, node.value);
            }
        }
```

Since all `hashTable` entries effectively contain the same `buckets` list, this  tries to add the entries `bucketSize` times.

To fix it you **must** in the constructor create a new `buckets` list for every `hashTable` entry:

```
    hashTable = createTable(bucketSize);
    for (int i = 0; i < bucketSize; i++) {
        hashTable[i] = createBucket();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

So your test does this:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    m.put("hi" + i, i);
```

Which mean that in your 10 thousand milliseconds, you need to do 1 million iterations, meaning 0.01 milliseconds are available per iteration, i.e. you need to process 100 iterations of this loop every millisecond.

Is it so surprising that it might time out? Remember, some time may be spent in garbage collection during that as well.

Although probably the real reason:
Your `put` calls `resize`, which creates a new MyHashMap and then uses `put`, which can then call `resize` and possibly go into a loop.

***P.S.***
I noticed that in your `put` method, you seem to needlessly be using `Integer` rather than `int`, which adds a small amount of overhead, boxing and unboxing the values.